# Trying to conditionally load a file or echo a line... what am I missing here?

Tags: php

Im not sure whats going wrong. I can get an echo of the DB value.. but once I send it through the if/elise I get nothing... ?

```
$user_act = ""; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($act_result)) {
$user_act = $row["meta_value"];
}

$user_act=$user_state;
if($user_state == 0){
 include '../load.php';
}
elseif($user_state <> 0){ 
echo '<h2 id="n_acrive" class="inactive" style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center;     font-family: "Raleway",Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 29px;"><strong> 0.00000000 </strong>    </h2>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to change

```
$user_act=$user_state;
```

to

```
$user_state=$user_act;
```

because you overwrite user_act immediately after database results.

Comment: Why would that be an issue... for future ref??

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!.. Still curious.. why is that an issue?

Comment: I was waiting whether someone would post it ;). +1. @NaN, You are not at all assigning the value of `$user_act` to your `$user_state` that's the reason.

Comment: @NaN because at that line the value of $user_state is 'empty' and that means you assign 'empty' to $user_act. So $user_act has no value no matter what situation/condition.

Answer (score 0):

why you changing again and again values of `$user_act` and what is value will be `$user_state` if you assign it `$user_act = $user_state` why you again checking with `$user_state`

```
$user_act = ""; 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($act_result)) {
$user_act = $row["meta_value"];
}

if(empty($user_act)){
 include '../load.php';
}
elseif(!empty($user_act)){ 
echo '<h2 id="n_acrive" class="inactive" style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center;     font-family: "Raleway",Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 29px;"><strong> 0.00000000 </strong>    </h2>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$user_act=$user_state;
```

to

```
$user_state=$user_act;
```